# Meteor puppeteer-extra could not find Chrome - Chromium revision 884014

Tags: node.js, meteor, puppeteer

A Meteor async function  works fine with `const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')` but when `const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra')` is used it gives error:

> Could not find expected browser (chrome) locally. Run `npm install` to download the correct Chromium revision (884014).

System:

Windows 10, Meteor@2.2, and the following is from package.json

> ```
> "pending-xhr-puppeteer": "^2.3.3",
> "puppeteer": "^8.0.0",
> "puppeteer-core": "^10.0.0",
> "puppeteer-extra": "^3.1.18",
> "puppeteer-extra-plugin-adblocker": "^2.11.11",
> "puppeteer-extra-plugin-block-resources": "^2.2.9",
> "puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth": "^2.7.8"
> ```

Preformed the requested instruction `npm install` for no avail.

Deleted node_modules folder and run `npm install` for no avail.

Downloaded chrome-win.zip revision 884014 from [here](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Win_x64/884014/), unzipped it and replace `App\node_modules\puppeteer\.local-chromium\win64-856583\chrome-win` with `App\node_modules\puppeteer\.local-chromium\win64-884014\chrome-win` for no avail.

Any suggestions is much appriciated.